# Flashy text in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, pstricks

I'm creating a [`beamer`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) presentation and I'm looking after some effects I could include to make my work more attractive. Is there a way to make a flashy text? I'm thinking about an alarm clock: you know when it rings the time appears, disapears, appears, disapears, ect.

On the other hand, I've seen other effects such as a text which gradually disappear (effect of fading).

It appears PSTricks may enable anyone to do something like that but would you have an exemple of code for both cases?

Answer (score 6):

Flashing text example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,nomouse,loop]{1.4}
  \strut Flashing\newframe[2.8] % [2.8] --> pause 1/2 as long as visible phase
\end{animateinline} text.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, there is a dedicated package for such things.

Comment: I like this very much. Can you explain why **\newframe[2.8]** a bit more?

Comment: @Dr. The initial frame rate is 1.4/s. Thus the first frame with the text is shown for 1/1.4 s = 0.714 seconds. Command `\newframe` takes an optional frame rate argument. `[2.8]` speeds up the animation for the following frames (there is only the one second empty frame) which will last only 1/2.8 s = 0.357 s. Thus, as the comment says, the text is visible twice as long as it is invisible which is more eye-pleasing.